# Redrawing the globe

Tags: google-earth-plugin

When toggling the visibility of 3D KmlPolygons or modifying style properties the globe doesn't update directly afterwards. Rather, you need to trigger an update by moving your mouse around. There's an internal redraw function that's only called at certain times, but I don't know how to invoke it.

To get the map to update I've made this function:

```
redraw : function (ge) {
    ge = setDefault(ge, this.ge);
    if (typeof obj == 'undefined' && ge) {
        Log.info('Earth redraw');
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(false);
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    } else {
        Log.error('Earth redraw failed');
    }
}
```

It toggles the window visibility and forces an update, but this causes a flash on some computers and isn't too elegant. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy the camera and set it again. I don't know if this will work, but if it works it should not make any flash
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

Comment: Um, after some more testing it seems this doesn't work. Any ideas why?